# Edit Method asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do a Edit page for users where the user can edit UserName and Email.
My controller looks like this:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(string Name="0")
    {
        using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var User = applicationContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(s => s.Name == Name).SingleOrDefault();
            if (User == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(User);
        }
    }


 [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        if (Name == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var UserUpdate = await applicationContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Name == Name);
            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<ApplicationUser>(UserUpdate, "", s => s.Name, s => s.Email))
            {
                try
                {
                    await applicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +"Try again, and if the problem persists, " +"see your system administrator.");
                }
            }
            return View(UserUpdate);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Model too:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DirectoryId { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> AllUsers { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        AllUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out I dont understand what is wrong here, I have som issues doing the edit because I always did it with an Int Id not an String Id.. it's strange for me can someone help me out ?

Comment: For a start, your POST method parameter needs to be your model, not `string`

Comment: @StephenMuecke already fixed that

Comment: *"I don't understand"* isn't a particularly useful description of a problem.  Consider this an opportunity to familiarize yourself with some basic debugging.  What specifically is happening when you step through this code in a debugger?  What are you expecting to happen?  Why?

Comment: @David I'm expecting to edit the Name and Email of the selected user but since ID isnt int but it's String it doesnt make anysense to me

Comment: @VolminAzeiteiro: Again, "it doesn't make any sense to me" also doesn't effectively describe an *actual problem*.  If this code isn't failing in any specific way then there isn't much we can do to help you.  It sounds like what you're looking for are just more tutorials and practice.  For example, the difference between an `int` and a `string` would be something you'd get in a variety of introductory C# tutorials.  Basically, and `int` is a numeric value and a `string` is a text value (which may or may not also be numbers, doesn't matter).

Comment: @David i know the diference between int and string but my problem is on the find, something like this : `Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);`

Comment: @VolminAzeiteiro: *"my problem is on the find"* - Perhaps you could elaborate on what that problem *is*?  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.  We don't know what trouble you're having.  It's also worth pointing out here that the code shown in the question doesn't make use of any `.Find()` method.  So, again... What is the problem you're having?  Take some time to *describe the problem*.

Comment: Didn't you have a primary key for your object? Or the propertty Name is unique like a nickname?

Comment: @carlosfcmendes the key is the Id, it's in the BaseEntity

Comment: The code was implemented by yourself, or you copy paste from some place? Your model (ApplicationUser) inherits from BaseEntity class, which should have an property that is the primary key. So you should get and edit your object by that property, instead by property Name.

Comment: Ok, so at `ActionResult Edit(string Name="0")`, give the correct name of your primary key, and then filter/get the object by that name, for example: (`var UserUpdate = await applicationContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.PrimaryKeyPropertyName == user.PrimaryKeyPropertyName );`)

Comment: @carlosfcmendes can you make an answer with a more direct example please? if it works I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said on my comment, at `ActionResult Edit(string Name="0")`, give the correct name of your primary key, and then filter/get the object by that name, for example: `(var UserUpdate = await applicationContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.PrimaryKeyPropertyName == user.PrimaryKeyPropertyName);)`

If you receive an object `ApplicationUser`, and supposing that object is your model of your view, and you have a property `Id`, it will be something like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int Id)
{
    using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        var User = applicationContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(s => s.Id ==  Id).SingleOrDefault();
        if (User == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(User);
    }
}


[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(ApplicationUser user)
{
    //Here will return every time NotFound/error, right? Where you defined Name?!
    /*if (Name == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }*/
    using (var applicationContext = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        var UserUpdate = await applicationContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == user.Id);

...
```

Comment: error on line 5, where "s.Id== Id" error is  "cannot implicitly convert type int to string

Comment: Change: `ActionResult Edit(string Id)` and `ApplicationUsers.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(Id))`

Comment: the get method is null, but when i type in the url, edit/1986a3ef-e032-44db-bc37-3b5eb0737408 it does show the profile that needs to be edited